# regex: OR operator between multiple options

Tags: php, regex

https://regex101.com/r/VY5LIG/1

## pattern

```
(?:faktura|kreditnota|kvittering)\b ?((?:\p{L}+\d+|(?:[\d ]|[^\p{L}])*))
```

## subject

```
faktura/kvittering 6856895
```

Why does this regex not match `kvittering` in this case?

The group needs to match the number

Comment: What are the requirements?

Comment: I need to match the number

Comment: Like [`.*(?:faktura|kreditnota|kvittering)\b ?\K((?:\p{L}+\d+|(?:[\d ]|[^\p{L}])*))`](https://regex101.com/r/VY5LIG/2)? Or [`\b(?:faktura|kreditnota|kvittering)\s*\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/VY5LIG/3)?

Comment: what does the `\K` do?

Comment: `\K` makes the regex engine omit the text matched so far from the match buffer. Note the second regex is much cleaner, but I may miss to meet some requirements you hide from us.

Comment: You can allow for a `/`-separated list of alternative words like this `(?:(?:kvittering|faktura|kreditnota)\/?)+\b ?((?:\p{L}+\d+|(?:[\d ]|[^\p{L}])*))`. Does that fit the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew create an answer :)

Comment: I have added an answer, please consider accepting/upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

The match you get is due to the fact that `(?:faktura|kreditnota|kvittering)` matched the first `faktura` and then `[^\p{L}]` matched the slash after the word.

If you grabbed all matches, you could get the last one, and access [Group 1 value].[1](https://regex101.com/r/VY5LIG/4)

Another way to get the last match would be to add `.*` at the start of the pattern and add `s` modifier to make sure `.` matches any char including a newline, and you would be able to get the match with a `preg_match` and again, grab Group 1 value. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VY5LIG/5).

However, from the description it seems you need to match a word from your first alternation group and then a number or some code that seems to consist of alphanumeric/word chars. Thus, I suggest using:

```
'~\b(?:faktura|kreditnota|kvittering)\s+\K\w+~'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VY5LIG/6).

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?:faktura|kreditnota|kvittering)` - any of the three words
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator that omits the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (you may use `[^\W_]` to match just alphanumeric ones).